# Почему New Orleans — не Нью-, а Новый Орлеан?

Tags: ономастика, переводы, названия, транслитерация

Почему одни названия частично переводятся, а другие полностью транслитерируются? Например, New York — это Нью-Йорк, а New Orleans — это Новый Орлеан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько способов передачи собственных имён с английского, напр. здесь упоминается о пяти:
https://www.top-technologies.ru/ru/article/view?id=31900

1) транслитерация;
2) транскрипция;
3) транспозиция;
4) калькирование,
5) комбинации этих приемов

Но можно предположить, что здесь современное русское наименование следует традиции передачи не из английского, а из **французского** языка, поскольку название городу (где и сейчас сильно влияние французской культуры) первоначально было дано французами (*La Nouvelle-Orléans*) и содержит часть, совпадающую с названием французского города, на русский обычно переводившимся как "**Орлеан**". В английском же варианте первая часть названия переведена с французского (как и в русском), а вторая - транслитерирована и произносится по правилам английского чтения слогов (близко к "Орлинс",  с ударением на втором слоге).